# How to find an element by ID in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to do something like this in C#

```
var id = "myID";
id.innerText = "Hello World";
```

I am a newbie and I'm sure this is pretty simple to do.

Comment: Hi gdoron, I have tried various solutions online, I can't seem to find anything that helps. Maybe I am searching for the wrong thing. Any direction would help me a great deal. Regards

Comment: I assume you're asking about XML. Keep in mind that you should _tell_ us if this question is about XML, so that we don't have to make the wrong assumption

Answer (score 9):

In ASP.NET, this is almost never necessary. For example, if you have a textbox called "txtMyTextBox", you can simply do `txtMyTextBox.Text = "Hello World";`. You can do this for any element that has the `runat="server"` attribute.

If you need to find it from a string, you can use `FindControl("txtMyTextBox")`, but note that this does not search recursively. It will only find direct children of the control you call it on. (You can use a [recursive algorithm](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/asp/recursively-finding-controls) to find controls recursively).

Finally, if you want to specifically refer to an element by it's HTML ID, you cannot do this. C# runs on the server and does not have direct access to the page.

Comment: Hi Jonathan I tried this: FindControl("txtMyTextBox").innerText but it doesn't work. Regards

Comment: @DahProblum yes but did you try the first thing he showed? Your code-behind will intellisense those elements with `runat="server"` so if you just start typing the ID value, it will show up.

Comment: @DahProblum: Firstly, why are you doing this? Why not `txtMyTextBox.Text = "...`? Second, what does "doesn't work" mean? (Please learn to think like a programmer by providing meaningful details.) Third, did you find recursively? Fourth, what type of control is this? TextBoxes do not have an `innerText` property. But they have a `Text` property. Isn't Intellisense working for you?

Comment: If you read his comment to my answer,you'll see we all initially misunderstood somewhat...

Answer (score 1):

There are loads of ways of doing that

```
XmlDocument() doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@"<SomeNodeName id = "myID">Hello World</SomeNodeName>";
```

Well you fooled me with the mention of innerText there.

I personally wouldn't do this unless I really really had to.

```
int positionInArray = myGame.IndexOf("MyDiv" + id.ToString());
```

There are a shed load of assumptions in the above. Finding out what could go wrong with it would be a very good learning exercise.

The answer that mentioned dictionary, that got removed after someone downvoted it would be a better approach

```
public class SomeObject
{
   private Dictionary<int, String> myGames;
   public SomeObject()
   {
      myGames = new Dictionary<int, string>();
   }
   public AddGame(int id, string desc)
   {
       myGames.Add(id,desc);
   }
   public string FindGameById(int id)
   {
      if(myGames.ContainsKey(id))
      {
         return myGames[id];
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tony, how about for something like this: int [] myGame = new int[]{3,4,5,6};
            int inc = 1;
           
            foreach (int i in myGame)
            { "MyDiv"+inc.toString() = i; inc++;} thanks